# How to install additional packages that had ignored by --no-install-recommends flag?

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

`--install-suggests` is not a solution - it offers install suggested packages for all installed in system packages - I want to install recommends only for one particular package.

P.S. Is there difference between recommends and suggested packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [Debian package management](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html) page:

> "Recommends"
>
> This declares a strong, but not absolute, dependency. Most users would
>   not want the package unless all of the packages listed in this field
>   are installed.
>
> "Suggests"
>
> This declares a weak dependency. Many users of this package may
>   benefit from installing packages listed in this field but can have
>   reasonable functions without them.

To install the packages ignored by the `--no-install-recommends` flag, you can consider [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/306629) nice trick suggested by Gilles (you'll need the `.deb` package though). The other option is to remove and install the package once again, this time without `--no-install-recommends`.

If you think why `apt-get install --reinstall --install-recommends` doesn't install these packages, [here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409573/apt-get-install-reinstall-install-recommends-not-installing-a-recommended-pa) an explanation.

Comment: I was wrong. 

P.S. I think, that there isn't any reason explaining why `apt install $PACKAGE --install-recommends` don't work. This command mean "install package with extra packages".  "Update" behavior - for `apt update` command only.